# installing usb wifi dongle

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek, dongle

I'm trying to install a USB wifi dongle under Ubuntu 16.04. It came with linux drivers supposedly compatible with linux 2.6x-4.1x. I tried to install the driver (called RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1) but I originally received the following error:

```
.../include/osdep_service.h:355:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_s
ignal’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
allow_signal(SIGTERM);
```

I found somewhere that adding this code to the script "osdep_service.h" prevents the error:

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 11, 0)
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#endif
```

But then I get a new error:

```
.../os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:734:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘cfg80211_roamed’
cfg80211_roamed(padapter->pnetdev
```

I read somewhere else that removing the #if LINUX... condition from this code would solve the problem:

```
cfg80211_roamed(padapter -> pnetdev
    # if LINUX_VERSION_CODE > KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 39) || defined(COMPAT_KERNEL_RELEASE)
    , notify_channel
    #endif
    , cur_network -> network.MacAddress
    , pmlmepriv -> assoc_req + sizeof(struct rtw_ieee80211_hdr_3addr) + 2
    , pmlmepriv -> assoc_req_len - sizeof(struct rtw_ieee80211_hdr_3addr) - 2
    , pmlmepriv -> assoc_rsp + sizeof(struct rtw_ieee80211_hdr_3addr) + 6
    , pmlmepriv -> assoc_rsp_len - sizeof(struct rtw_ieee80211_hdr_3addr) - 6
    , GFP_ATOMIC
);
```

Unfortunately I now have the following error:

```
.../os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:734:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘cfg80211_roamed’
cfg80211_roamed(padapter->pnetdev
```

Could someone explain to me how to install this wifi dongle? I'm not very familiar with linux.
Thanks.

Comment: It does not appear. I can see it as 0dba:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. with lsub, but I don't see it with lspci.

Comment: Can soomeone please answer this!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess for linux the Wifi Dongle is automatically detected. I use Cana Kit Dongle and it requires no drivers or changes made in WiFi Settings. But recently bought teratec. It doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure about that.

Edit: You need a driver. Download the driver from the internet and run

`sudo insmod <driver-file>`